# (VB6) What is Attribute VB_Exposed for, and how is it modified?

Tags: vb6, attributes, diff

I was wondering what VB6 uses Attribute VB_Exposed for, and how it is filled in. It is invisible when you open up your class file within VB, but present at the top of pretty much every class when you open it up in notepad.

```
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = True  '<--What is this for?
```

The reason I'm asking is that recently code I committed somehow changed this value to false, and it prevented my project from compiling. I only discovered that this attribute changed by doing a diff with TortoiseSVN. I still have no idea how it changed in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Attribute VB_Exposed` differentiates between, well, exposed and Private classes.

Exposed classes are those a client can make use of and Private classes are only usable within the object module (EXE, ActiveX EXE, DLL, OCX).

This is a place where they used another word instead of overloading the term "Public" which has at least two meanings in VB6 and can cause newbies no end of confusion.  This meaning is "Exposed" which means *public* in the sense of "published" for external use.

If your "content damager" is altering this I'd look for other serious things to worry about as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you know how VB determines what this attribute should be? Whether it is a setting at the project level or the class/control/form level?

Comment: You set it on each Class through the IDE's Instancing property.  Depending on the type of Project it defaults to different values.

Comment: +1 @brainfreeze91  Did you change the instancing property of the relevant class? Did you change the project type (project properties menu option, general tab) which is saved in the VBP file? Changing the project type could change the VB_Exposed for every class.

Comment: Thank you! I discovered what caused it. Apparently I double clicked my control I was committing (which created a new project that opened it) and ignored this warning message: "'<control name>' can not be public in this type of project. The item has been changed to private." Ugh so it was my fault that it got changed! Thanks for the help!